# Return messages from .sql file run from MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

We have an access application, which runs SQL statements using something like this snippet below. Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve anything that comes up in the messages tab, if the script was run straight in SQL Management Studio? So, print statements and errors?

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "ScriptHere"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075100/catching-error-message-from-sql-server-in-vba-in-excel) is sort of along the same lines.

Comment: Also, take a look [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic300275-131-1.aspx) as well.