# How to get the PRINT output messages from SQL Server procedure in Excel VBA?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

My Excel VBA module opens a new connection and calls some procedure from SQL Server returning a dataset. Also, the procedure makes a lot of PRINT messages which can be useful to track the logs of the calculation process.

Usually there are no "red" errors in the output.

Is there a way to capture `PRINT` output stream on VBA side and write it to special log Excel sheet?

If no - I'd develop a logger table, log procedure and perform refactoring of the T-SQL code, that can take long time..

Comment: `PRINT` statements are useful for debugging but should be removed for any code running in production. So yeah, get rid of them and use a proper logging table.

Comment: Do they show up in the Errors collection as here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31075668/73226