# VBA SQL Bulk insert excepton handling

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, csv

I have to execute CSV records as batch by batch to SQL Server. In the macro, I am framing SQL query based on the record in the foreign key. So, I can not go for BULK Insert here.

I written code to iterate 100 rows and save in String like below:

```
Insert into table ('name','address','region') values ('Test','xxx-test-address',1);
Insert into table ('name','address','region') values ('Test','xxx-test-address',1);
Insert into table ('name','address','region') values ('Test','xxx-test-address',1);
Insert into table ('name','address','region') values ('Test','xxx-test-address',1);
```

Now, I am executing 100 SQL inserts against SQL Server. Let's say if error is thrown at 50th row then remaining 50 rows are not executed and error throwing at VBA.

My question is how do I find which row is throwing error?

If can not be achieved in this approach, please let me know the approach to achieve. Since 10000 or more records will be in CSV, I can not execute the records in iteration. This will hit database many times.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `GO` batch separator command which could help u.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? sorry, I do not get how to catch the exception

Comment: Since `Go` is a batch operator, if I receive error in one of the inserts then still other inserts be executed? Also, how do I get the information of the exception?

Comment: What is the Error?  Is it a key constraint or a datatype mismatch error?

Comment: @ThomasInzina, let's say I execute 15 insert statements. one of the insert threw data error (let's say 8th insert statement): a) if I use Go, rest 7 inserts will be executed? b) how SQL error will be thrown back to VBA?

Comment: I would check for any data type mismatch errors while building the SQL.  You can then choose how to handle them before they are an issue.  If you are getting any key constraint errors then I would create a query to find which record IDs are invalid and then fix them before they're an issue.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, yes correct, I have if exist condition in my actual insert statement. But, let's say if something happens (I do not know how), I want to capture the corresponding insert statement with error information and continue with the further insert statements execution

Comment: @KarthickRaju, this is an idea, not sure if it even works. You can try adding `PRINT` messages at the end of every `INSERT` statement, that will indicate what statement was executed and then try to capture them. This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075100/catching-error-message-from-sql-server-in-vba-in-excel/31075668#31075668

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for the URL. Have tried already. I think I could not do what I want to. So, I am going to execute the 100 inserts inside of Try/Catch. If error throws, I would gather exception details - ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), to analyze which record raised the issue