# How do I read messages from an ADO Execute that doesn't return a recordset?

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb, execute

I'm using VBA and sending a query to an ADODB, the Conn.Execute method.

How do I retrieve the messages? As an example:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

or

```
1,670 rows inserted.
```

or

```
Error starting at line : 19 in command -
TRUNCATE TABLE SYSBO.GA_OPS_TMP_ORDERS
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

Comment: You'll need a class module, a `Private WithEvents adoConnection As ADODB.Connection`, and handlers for the events fired by the API.

Comment: Thanks M, sounds like the right path. Do you have an example? Is that in the declaration or the creation of the connection?

Comment: I'd put up an answer, but it would be more akin to some blog post or tutorial than a SO answer, and I don't have an hour to spend doing that right now... I suggest you try implementing that and then ask a more specific question if/when you get a roadblock - your question is basically *too broad* to be a good fit for this site right now.

Comment: Well, found one [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.ca/2008/12/how-to-use-connection-events-in-ado-vba.html), should get you started. "User-defined type not defined" sounds like you need to add an actual reference to the ADODB type library. You can't handle events on late-bound types AFAIK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching error message from SQL Server in VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075100/catching-error-message-from-sql-server-in-vba-in-excel)

Comment: ^ that's for reading errors, for other messages, I agree with Mat's Mug.